# Accessing a particular element through DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm having trouble with DOM. I'm trying to access the class of a particular `<span>` element.

HTML:

```
<span><span class="abc">*</span><label for="sometext"></label></span>
```

I want to access the class 'abc' of the `<span>` element, and I have the `<label>` element with me.

Here's what I'd done:

```
var parent=$(label[0]).parent();
var class=$(parent[0]).childNodes[0].attr("class");
```

EDIT:The previous sibling of the  appears to be some Text node!!..Don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can simply use:

```
var classes = $(label[0]).prev().attr('class');
```

I'd recommend not naming your 'class' variable 'class' as it is a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: Not working!..The previous sibling is a 'text' node!..Can't see how

Comment: If that is the case, then something is going wrong with assigning  label[0], can you tell us how/where you assign that value? See: http://jsfiddle.net/Bs9A9/1/

Comment: Hey, I found out the mistake. Turns out in some cases the layout is like this: <span>&nbsp;<label for="sometext"></label>

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
$('label')
      .prev('span')  // get the previous span of label
      .attr('class');  // get class of the span.
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nGw3E/2/)**

or

```
$('label')
      .siblings('span')  // get the previous span of label
      .first()
      .attr('class');  // get class of the span
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wkZ3Z/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var sibling = $('label').siblings('span').first();
var class = $(sibling).attr('class');
```

Comment: he wants to find the sibling span's class not its parent: 
`var class= $(parent).find('span').attr("class");`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('label').siblings('span').attr('class');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cf9Qn/